# Folder Structure in Codeigniter HMVC Extension

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I new with hmvc and I want to ask about folder structure in codeigniter with hmvc extension.
I used to arrange application controller folder for admin and public like this:

Application

--Controllers/

----admin/

------login.php

------dashboard.php

----blog.php

----about.php

----contact.php

So that page could be access with {base_url}/admin/login, {base_url}/admin/dashboard for Admin and for Public is {base_url}/blog , {base_url}/about etc.

With hmvc extension, how to achive url like that? for now i make my filename with admin_something.php, but that is look messy for me.

Application/

--Modules/

----admin_dashboard/

------Controllers/

--------admin_dashboard.php

------Models/

------Views/

----home/

------Controllers/

--------home.php

------Models/

------Views/

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple controllers in your module. So make a folder admin with admin controller in your module's controller folder.

```
mymodule
- controller
  - home.php
  - admin/admin_dashboard.php
- model
  - model.php
- view
  - home_view.php
  - admin/admin_view.php
```

To access the modules

`echo Modules::run('mymodule/home/methodname');`

`echo Modules::run('mymodule/admin/admin_dashboard/methodname');`

Comment: But how can we access admin_dashboard controller by URL ?

Comment: In that case you have to create a config dir inside the module and create a routes.php with entry 
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1' so that requests will get executed as per controllers in admin folder